# Circular scroll bar

Tags: user-research, usability-testing, scrolling

I have been developing a circular motion scroll,

For Instance: if you rotate the circle clockwise the page will scroll down and if you rotate the circle anticlockwise the page would scroll up.

Though the mapping of this constraint is quite different. But do you think this would make the experience of scroll fun, its like steering the page up and down rather than scrolling.

Comment: Might work to an extent on a hand held, touch friendly device - but would not recommend it for a mouse based interaction. Why complicate the simple?

Comment: there is the obvious example of the iPod that had the wheel to scroll up and down - but as others say - this won't be fun with a mouse, or on a mobile screen where it is more natural to slide your thumb up and down.

Comment: Make sense as a hypothesis, but do you recommend me to go ahead to try and test at least we'll have numbers and facts to support. I would love to test this out...and I could even see if could modify it someway that would be helpful with mouse even.

Comment: Consider why people are using your app. Are they there to play with a scroller or to accomplish something else? I'd suggest innovating on features that directly help people accomplish their tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It totally depends on where do you deploy this concept, and what your target Users are.
If you are targeting users who do not interact with Websites or Apps much, then its a bad idea, as they will be confused.
For example

1. If your site or app is something like Amazon(for shopping), we can assume that all type of Users would be using your service, so in this case it would be better to stick to the traditional scroll method.
2. If your site is more like Tumblr, Instagram, even blogs, which you're sure what kind of Users you're providing your service to then I would say go for Steering Scroll.

I hope i was able to convey this properly. Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh it was just perfect, That meas I am going on good. Because I am developing this scroll for information based website rather than e-commerce. Thanks

Comment: Go for it then, its way cooler and would be fun to use in this case

Comment: Yeah, Exactly how I thought. though its not easy to develop. Too much mathematics involved ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you open your favorite drawing software and try to draw a circle with your mouse freehand (using a pencil tool, not a shape tool), you'll find that it's quite challenging. Making circles with your mouse is a difficult task that requires very advanced motor skills and most regular people will find it very inconvenient - let alone people with disabilities.

It will not be fun. It will be quite frustrating for the absolute majority of users.

Comment: That is true too, but I also believe people love change, it might be frustrating because I am going to break the stereotypes for scroll, but when they start using it ...hence become skillful enough it would be fun

Comment: By the way you will like that I am not going to make it as difficult as drawing a circle..it would be thrice as easy then drawing a circle

Comment: It won't be frustrating because of the conventions. It will be frustrating because of the anatomy of the human hand. I'm afraid that you will need to change that too, in order for your concept to become fun.

Comment: Agreed. But the way I am building it and keeping in mind my target user, it won't be...I will love to share the prototype once I'm done building it..I hope my organization let me share :)

Answer (score 1):

Will using the mouse wheel also scroll the page? Many people use the mouse-wheel to scroll the page, rather than trying to manipulate their mouse in a circular motion (which will not be easy to do for some people).

I am all for adding fun into the experience, but there is nothing fun or exciting about scrolling - it is a simple utility which comes with certain expectations. If you deviate from these expectations, expect resistance from your users.

Personally, I would not waste development time and money on trying to make scrolling "fun". No one will expect it to be fun and I predict it will cause a lot of user frustration, and could cause you some embarrassment.

Instead, choose something else in your solution to make fun - ideally something related to the primary features of your solution.

Comment: Again as said it is not primarily for fun, but I am primarily building this for offer resistance and user easiness for reading a long article. As per now I have concluded that rotating in a circular motion would be implemented on touch screens and for mouse I would still use circular navigation but it would be divided and there would be use of anchor links..circular is just to reduce distance between two navigation option in case there are multiple section to the page and there is a long scroll . since mouse wheel is small in diameter I can control the same on UI

Comment: Ok - did not see this is for touch too. With touch, using circular gestures is not a common gesture and few people would know about it. Typically with touch, scrolling through an article is simple swipe up or down. Why deviate from this expected touch gesture?

Comment: Have you tried playing Car parking 3D ? I have and best thing about that game is simulation of the steering and it feels like real drive instead of using arrow icon to turn. I have observed people loved it. I have derived my conclusion from that game that a steering could  engage user as if they are steering the page and they are not going to remove their thumb off the screen once they start reading. now I dnt want them to stop reading for second, then scroll and start reading again I want them to keep reading they don't have to stop. make sense?

Comment: Does not make sense. Playing a game is very different to scrolling an article. The goal of game is to play to win, the goal of reading an article is to be able to read all of it. Swiping as you read is neither difficult or disruptive, and is the expected UI behaviour. If you introduce something which is not expected UI behaviour then you are introducing disruption which will force them to stop reading.

Comment: Agreed, it is not a game..I just referred that game just give you a background. I am not thinking reading an article as playing a game. Yes I am introducing new way of movement but I am think it would be less disruptive than swiping. That's my point.

Comment: Take case you are reading a PDF of 361 pages . but you have to read only page number 250-257 .. So you swipe or jump to page 250 (coz I'm not removing swipe operation of course that would be stupid) then once person start reading he doesn't have move his eyes neither move his thumb too much like swiping then removing then again keeping it on screen then swipe and then pulling off his thumb and so on. He just have to rotate and keep his eyes steady

Comment: Have you actually tried this idea on any real users? Because it seems you are very confident that this will not introduce friction, but have you any indications of this from testing it? For me, it sounds like you are putting a lot of development time in something that could very well be useless without having user feedback. Also, keep in mind that your users will spend so little of their time on your site/app that you have a very small window to catch their attention. If they just get irritated by not figuring out how to scroll, you will probably lose them forever.

Comment: If you are not getting rid of swipe then why introduce something that is more complex than swipe? Swipe is the easiest of all the gestures.

Comment: @dpandersson I am building it and since so many of them don't agree to it I want to build it more badly, because I think its worth trying to do something different. It succeed then it is a win if not I'll know why. I am not confident about I am just positive. I know the way I have envisioned it. :). Even if it dnt work I'm full of ideas.. Nobody accepts a new thing, everyone is afraid of breaking conventions but sometimes it works and when it works it Legendary . Please dnt mind my big words I'm a dreamer and not afraid of failing

Comment: @splatz I'm talking about experience its a usability only should be used when its supposed to be. So I dnt mind making a layer of the same usability for a better reason

Comment: @DeWySady  There is a time and place for trying something different, but changing scrolling though an article is not one of them ;-) 

By all means go ahead, but please test your solution with people before you release it :-)

Comment: Of course I'm not releasing it Testing it is first thing I would do. I would come back to this post with the results and we will all have a new learning out of it . don't you think